# Two arraylist of objects - finding value from one and setting as the other

Tags: java, csv, arraylist, hashmap

I have two CSV files, one `"crimeUSA.csv"` with the headers `state`, `city`, `population` etc. and one `StatesAbbreviations` with the headers `states, abbrev` . First I read the `"crimeUSA.csv"` file and create `CityCrime` objects.

Instead of using the state in this file, I want to match it with the state in the `StatesAbbreviations` file and set the state as the appropriate abbreviation value instead. I previously had the states and matching abbreviations hardcoded in the setter for state but I have removed it as was pretty long and ugly. This is why the `setState()` is commented out in the `readCrimeData()` method below.

My main class StartApp:

```
public class StartApp {

    public static ArrayList<CityCrime> crimes = new ArrayList<CityCrime>();
    public static ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    /**
     * Start point for app. Directs the reads from file and shows the menu
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            CityCrime.readAbbrevData();
            readCrimeData("crimeUSA.csv");
            System.out.println("Total cities read: " + getTotalCities());
            showMenu();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    /**
     * Reads the crime data for each city from entered file
     * Adds the CityCrime objects to the crimes ArrayList
     */
    public static void readCrimeData(String fromFile) {

        File file = new File(fromFile);

        FileReader fileReader;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        
        String crimeInfo;
        String[] stats;
        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            crimeInfo = bufferedReader.readLine();
            crimeInfo = bufferedReader.readLine();

            do {
                CityCrime crime = new CityCrime(); // Default constructor
                stats = crimeInfo.split(",");
                {
                    if (stats[0] != null) {
                        crime.setCity(stats[0]);
                    }
                    if (stats[1] != null) {
                        //crime.setState(stats[1]);
                        crime.setAbbreviation(stats[1]);
                    }
                    if (stats[2] != null) {
                        if (Integer.parseInt(stats[2]) >= 0) {
                            crime.setPopulation(Integer.parseInt(stats[2]));
                        }
                    }
                    if (stats[3] != null) {
                        if (Integer.parseInt(stats[3]) >= 0) {
                            crime.setMurder(Integer.parseInt(stats[3]));
                        }
                    }

                    if (stats[4] != null) {
                        if (Integer.parseInt(stats[4]) >= 0) {
                            crime.setRobbery(Integer.parseInt(stats[4]));
                        }
                    }

                    if (stats[5] != null) {
                        if (Integer.parseInt(stats[5]) >= 0) {
                            crime.setAssault(Integer.parseInt(stats[5]));
                        }
                    }

                    if (stats[6] != null) {
                        if (Integer.parseInt(stats[6]) >= 0) {
                            crime.setBurglary(Integer.parseInt(stats[6]));
                        }
                    }

                    if (stats[7] != null) {
                        if (Integer.parseInt(stats[7]) >= 0) {
                            crime.setLarceny(Integer.parseInt(stats[7]));
                        }
                    }

                    if (stats[8] != null) {
                        if (Integer.parseInt(stats[8]) >= 0) {
                            crime.setMotorTheft(Integer.parseInt(stats[8]));
                        }
                    }
                    crime.setTotalCrimes(Integer.parseInt(stats[3]), Integer.parseInt(stats[4]), Integer.parseInt(stats[5]), Integer.parseInt(stats[6]), Integer.parseInt(stats[7]), Integer.parseInt(stats[8]));
                }
                crimes.add(crime);
                System.out.println(crime);

                crimeInfo = bufferedReader.readLine();

            } while (crimeInfo != null);

            fileReader.close();
            bufferedReader.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Next I have the `CityCrime` class:

```
public class CityCrime {
    
    
    //Instance variables
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private int population;
    private int murder;
    private int robbery;
    private int assault;
    private int burglary;
    private int larceny;
    private int motorTheft;
    public int totalCrimes;
    public String stateAbb;

    public static ArrayList<CityState> abbreviations = new ArrayList<CityState>(); 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        
    }
    
    public String getAbbreviation() {
        return stateAbb;
    }
    
    public String setAbbreviation(String state) {
        for(CityState statebb : abbreviations) {
            if(state == statebb.getState()) {
                stateAbb = statebb.getAbbreviation();
            }
        }
        return stateAbb;
    }
    
    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    
    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }


    public int getPopulation() {
        return population;
    }


    public void setPopulation(int population) {
        this.population = population;

    }


    public int getMurder() {
        return murder;
    }


    public void setMurder(int murder) {
        this.murder = murder;
    }

        //etc

    public static void readAbbrevData() {

        File file = new File("StatesAbbreviations.csv");

        FileReader fileReader;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        String abbrevInfo;
        String[] stats;

        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            abbrevInfo = bufferedReader.readLine();
            abbrevInfo = bufferedReader.readLine();

            do {
                CityState abbrevs = new CityState(); // Default constructor
                stats = abbrevInfo.split(",");
                {
                    if (stats[0] != null) {
                        abbrevs.setState(stats[0]);
                    }
                    if (stats[1] != null) {
                        abbrevs.setAbbreviation(stats[1]);
                    }
                }
                abbreviations.add(abbrevs);
                //System.out.println(abbrevs);
                System.out.println("State: " + abbrevs.getState() + "Abbreviation= " + abbrevs.getAbbreviation());

                abbrevInfo = bufferedReader.readLine();

            } while (abbrevInfo != null);

            fileReader.close();
            bufferedReader.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The `CityState` class (not sure whether necessary, as not sure if I'm going in the right direction, or over complicating in my head):

```
public class CityState {
    
    public String state;
    public String abbreviation;

    public CityState() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
        
    }

    public void setAbbreviation(String abbreviation) {
        this.abbreviation = abbreviation;
        
    }
    
    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
    
    public String getAbbreviation() {
        return abbreviation;
    }

}
```

So, with my current method in the `CityCrime` class, when I set the abbreviation, I think the issue is that for each `CityState`, it is checking the state read from the `"CrimeUSA.csv"`, and obviously it isn't going be equal each time, and `null` is then printed. E.g, this is an example of the output:

```
----------------------------------------------------
City                     : Holmdel Township
State                    :       null
Population               :      16957
Murder                   :          0
Assault                  :          2
Robbery                  :          1
Burglary                 :         25
Larceny                  :        186
Motor Theft              :          7
Violent crime            :          3
Possession crime         :        218
----------------------------------------------------
City                     :  Hopatcong
State                    :       null
Population               :      16013
Murder                   :          0
Assault                  :          3
Robbery                  :          1
Burglary                 :         17
Larceny                  :        124
Motor Theft              :          5
Violent crime            :          4
Possession crime         :        146
----------------------------------------------------
```

I have made an update to my code. I have moved the `readAbbrevData()` to the `StartApp` class. And I'm using a HashMap:

```
        File file = new File("StatesAbbreviations.csv");

        FileReader fileReader;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;
        String abbrevInfo;
        String[] stats;

        try {
            fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

            abbrevInfo = bufferedReader.readLine();
            abbrevInfo = bufferedReader.readLine();

            do {
                final var stateToAbbreviation = new HashMap<String, String>();
                stats = abbrevInfo.split(",");
                {
                    if (stats[0] != null) {
                        stateToAbbreviation.put(stats[0], stats[1]);
                    }
                }
                for (String key: stateToAbbreviation.keySet()){
                    System.out.println(key +" = "+stateToAbbreviation.get(key));
                }

                abbrevInfo = bufferedReader.readLine();

            } while (abbrevInfo != null);

            fileReader.close();
            bufferedReader.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

My issue is now, setting it, and using as part of the crime object in `CityCrime` class. In my `readCrimeData()` method in the `StartApp` class I am currently using:

```
if (stats[1] != null) {
                        crime.setAbbreviation(stats[1]);
                        //crime.setState(stats[1]);
}
```

I am a beginner in Java, so appreciate help in simpler terms if possible to help me understand. Thankyou

Comment: **Currently you are only calling `readAbbrevData` in a separate main, the arraylist therefore remains empty.** This might be a good place where a resource could be used instead of a file, but that depends on the use case.

Comment: One big problem with your class is that if anything is null or possibly empty that the values are set to zero. That means that the values are not correct: unknown is not the same as zero when it comes to crime - or anything for that matter.

Comment: I have no idea why the static method for your `CityState` is in `CityCrime` by the way.

Comment: @Maarten, thankyou I appreciate your comments. Apologies - I am new to the formatting ways of StackOverflow, and did not mean to 'shout' or put anything in bold. I've made a couple changes which I think are small improvements if you want to check. Thankyou

Comment: Oh, dear, rather new to Java too it seems, here is a [snippet](https://gist.github.com/owlstead/33b4e73ac73c4cecaeca3d5b1c6bd1a3) on how to program that kind of thing. Please don't extend the question beyond what is originally asked, otherwise everything comments / answers all become jumbled up. Main thing: the hashmap needs to be declared **outside of the loop**.

Comment: Very new! But I am trying. Thankyou, that looks a lot cleaner also. Ok got it, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is that you use  == to compare Strings. References of course are different. You should use equals instead and it will work.
Replace
`if(state == statebb.getState())`
with  `if(state.equals(statebb.getState()))`

There you can also just return response on the way, instead of continuing iterating.

```
   public String setAbbreviation(String state) {
       for(CityState statebb : abbreviations) {
           if(state.equals(statebb.getState())) {
               return statebb.getAbbreviation();
           }
       }
       return "UNKNOWN";
   }
```

But the better option here would be instead of CityState class to save in a Map
`Map<String,String> stateToAbbreviation;`

And after that instead of interate over a list and check for abbreviation your method reduce to:

```
    public String setAbbreviation(String state) {
         return stateToAbbreviation.getOrDefault(state,"UNKNOWN");
    }
```

Comment: Also creating incomplete objects  as you do with CityState is bad practice. And also you can use try-with-resources. The way you close streams is wrong, if you have an error during reading/write, that would remain open. You either should've put with finally, but better use try-with-resources. If you want ping me in private and I will show you how you can be improved.

Comment: thankyou for your reply. I tried the state.equals but 'null' is still returned in the output. Do you have any idea why this would be? I've tried to ping you in chat, but I'm new to stack overflow and can't seem to find it so please message me first if you can. I'm trying to use the map method but can't seem to get it either. Thankyou I appreciate your help

Comment: You cannot just start a chat or ping somebody in chat unless they have been participating in chat before. If you become a somewhat high rep user you will quickly appreciate that "superping" isn't enabled for all users (mods can superping; I'm mod at [crypto.se]0.